# Why is MATLAB unable to solve this equation?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I tried to solve the following equation on MATLAB:

```
f = 2*x*exp(sin(x)) - 1/(x^3 + 1) + (3*x^3)/(x^3 + 1)^2 + x^2*exp(sin(x))*cos(x)
```

I plotted this function on desmos and found that this function becomes 0 infinitely many times in the interval (negative infinity, positive infinity) but I am only interested in the zeroes in an interval `[a,b]` where `a` and `b` are already given to me.

I plotted the same function on desmos and it becomes 0 at 3 points in the interval `[0,5]` but MATLAB only reports one solution of the three. Keep in mind that I used `solve()` to get the solution and I didn't know how to specify the interval in which I wanted to find the solution. And due to some reason I got the warning that symbolic solving didn't work here and that MATLAB needed to revert to `vpasolve` to get the answer. I don't know if this piece of information is significant but I'm still reporting it.

So here's what I wrote:

```
syms x;
f= 2*x*exp(sin(x)) - 1/(x^3 + 1) + (3*x^3)/(x^3 + 1)^2 + 
x^2*exp(sin(x))*cos(x);
solve(f)
```

what I got is something like this:

```
Warning: Unable to solve symbolically. Returning a numeric solution using 
vpasolve. 
> In solve (line 304) 

ans =

0.29525380332824351672413789113445
```

which is one correct solution but that's not the whole answer that I expected.

Comment: Numeric solutions always consist of a single value. You can explicitly use `vpasolve` to find solutions within your interval. Call it repeatedly with different start values to get different solutions.

Comment: can you please post a sample code of how to do it. I am new to matlab and coding in general

Answer (score 3):

You can add conditions to your equation in order to locate all of the roots on `[0,5]`.

First, we plot the `f(x)`:

```
syms x;
f(x) = 2*x*exp(sin(x)) - 1/(x^3 + 1) + (3*x^3)/(x^3 + 1)^2 + x^2*exp(sin(x))*cos(x);

figure(1)
clf

t = linspace(0,5,1000);
plot(t,f(t))
grid
```

[image]

We can roughly split interval into 3 parts, and now look for roots on each of the intervals, one by one:

```
assume(x>0 & x< 1)
x1 = solve(f(x)==0);

assume(x>1 & x< 3)
x2 = solve(f(x)==0);

assume(x>3 & x< 5)
x3 = solve(f(x)==0);

% plot found solutions:
xs = [x1,x2,x3];
hold on
plot(xs,f(xs),'*r','LineWidth',4)
```

[image]

Comment: So you are saying that we will need to know already that there are 3 roots of the function and then split the function accordingly... But what if I want to find a generic approach for finding solutions to equations in an interval. Can I do that on MATLAB?

Comment: @VaibhavChopra what do you mean by "generic" solution? In this case MATLAB can't find symbolical solution

Comment: By generic approach I meant that I was looking for code that could be used for any function without changing the code. But I think MATLAB will require some prior information when finding solutions to functions with infinite roots

Comment: @VaibhavChopra that is a complex problem

Comment: Yeah I understood... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this where you cycle through different start values for vpasolve

```
syms x
eq1=2*x*exp(sin(x)) - 1/(x^3 + 1) + (3*x^3)/(x^3 + 1)^2 + x^2*exp(sin(x))*cos(x)==0;
for g=1:5
    h(g)=vpasolve(eq1,g);
end
```

and then just record all unique values of h as solutions to your equation